# Zero-initialization of POD types

Tags: c++, initialization

```
struct Foo
{
    char name[10];
    int  i;
    double d;
};
```

I know that I can zero-initialize all the members of such POD type with:

```
Foo foo = {0};
```

Can I further simplify this to:

```
Foo foo = {};
```

Like native arrays? (`int arr[10] = {};`)

---

I'm not asking when initializing with `{0}`, will the members except the first are zero-initialized. I know the answer to that question is yes. I'm asking if the first `0` can be  omitted syntactically.

Most of the tutorials I found on this subject suggest using `{0}`, none using `{}`, e.g, [this guide](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=171), and it's explained as *This works because aggregate initialization rules are recursive;*, which gives more confusion than explanation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's terribly misleading. `int n;` is "like default constructing", but doesn't set to zero. It's rather that "`{}` is like value-initializing the data".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written, this is aggregate initialization. The applicable rule is (§8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]/p7):

> If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its *brace-or-equal-initializer* or, if
>   there is no *brace-or-equal-initializer*, from an empty initializer
>   list (8.5.4).

The relevant parts of §8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]/p3 is:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined
>   as follows:
>
> - If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is
>     value-initialized.
> - [irrelevant items omitted]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

In short, sub-aggregates are recursively aggregate-initialized from an empty initializer list. Everything else is value-initialized. So the end result is everything being value-initialized, with everything being a POD, value-initialization means zero-initialization.

---

If `T` is POD but not an aggregate, then aggregate initialization doesn't apply, so you hit the second bullet point in §8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]/p3, which results in value-initialization of the entire object instead. POD classes must have a trivial (and so not-user-provided) default constructor, so value-initialization for them means zero-initialization as well.