# extended initializer list and uninitialized members

Tags: c++

In the old days structure like that:

```
typedef struct A {
    int m_i;
    int m_j;
} A;
```

Allocated on the heap or declared locally in a function without being `memset` would have its members uninitialized.

However, to my utter surprise this little program shows it is always set to 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct A {
    int m_i;
    int m_j;
} A;

void f(const A& a) {
    printf("i=%i, j=%i\n", a.m_i, a.m_j);
}

void y() {
    f({10});
}

int main() {
    y();
    return 0;
}
```

Built using `g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp`

I would just in case defined a constructor to make sure they are zero, but my various tests show (using code found on the internet) that I don't have to.

Is this a shear coincidence or extended initializer list is a guarantor of having memory being memset?

Comment: What is an "extended initializer list"? That's not really a thing in C++.

Comment: I don't think there were any good old days where the second member wouldn't get initialized to 0.

Comment: Not sure what the point of the `y()` function is BTW.

Comment: Fun fact: C++ already know whether an identifier is a `struct` or a `class` or a whatever, so `typedef struct A { ... } A;` can just be a plain `struct A { ...};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef struct A {
    int m_i;
    int m_j;
} A;
```

is an aggregate.  When you initialize an aggregate with a *braced-init-list* it uses each element in the list to initialize each member of the aggregate.  If you don't provide enough elements in the *braced-init-list* then each subsequent member is guaranteed to be value initialized, which for fundamental types means they are zero initialized..

Comment: Would you be able to provide a reference, please? I have noticed that but I don't know if this is a matter of well defined behavior or particular compiler stuff.

Comment: @Grzegorz Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804188/zero-initialization-of-pod-types